# In C#, Is it possible to refactor my Post and Put methods to eliminated code duplication?

Tags: c#, rest, functional-programming, refactoring, code-duplication

I have the following two methods:

```
        private string Post(string url, ByteArrayContent content, AuthenticationToken token = null) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (token != null) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);
            }

            return client.PostAsync(url, content)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result;
        }

        private string Put(string url,  ByteArrayContent content,  AuthenticationToken token) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (token != null) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);
            }

            return client.PutAsync(url, content)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result;
        }
```

As you can see, there are only difference is that one method invoked `PostAsync` while the other method invokes `PutAsync`.

Would it be possible to write a single function like:

```
        private string Send(string url,  ByteArrayContent content,  AuthenticationToken token, String functionName) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (token != null) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);
            }

            return client[sendFunction](url, content)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result;
        }
```

And then I'd be able to turn each of the other functions into one liners like:

```
private string Post(string url, ByteArrayContent content, AuthenticationToken token = null) {
    this.Send(url, content, token, "PostAsync");
}
```

... It would be even better if I could pass the function or function name in a way which would typesafe.

Comment: something like [this?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MDcREE)

Comment: Something like that.  Even better if I could simplify the parameters on the consumer side so it can be expressed something like `Common(url, content, token, HttpClient.PutAsync)` or otherwise remove the need to iterate url and content three times each.

Comment: AFAIK there is no concept of "thiscall delegate" in C#. I think [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4SXn2T) is max

Comment: @Selvin, cheers for the help.  I think I prefer what I did down below a little better though I'd still like to see if improved.... I'll wait a bit to see if anyone knows better than either of us.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Playing a bit further with the response from Selvin, I was able to come up with:

```
        private string Post(string url, ByteArrayContent content, AuthenticationToken token = null) {
            return this.Send(token, (client) => client.PostAsync(url, content));
        }

        private string Put(string url,  StringContent content,  AuthenticationToken token) {
            return this.Send(token, (client) => client.PutAsync(url, content));
        }

        private string Send(AuthenticationToken token,  Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> sendFunction) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (token != null) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);
            }

            return sendFunction(client)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result;
        }
```

... which is almost what I want, but I still need to express "client" twice.

Does C# have any notation which will allow me to remove this redundancy?

Or should I accept this as "as good as it gets"?

Comment: The redundancies can be removed by using `HttpClient.SendAsync` instead of PostAsync and PutAsync and just providing either HttpMethod.Post or HttpMethod.Put as parameters.

Comment: @ckuri, that would really be more trading than removing redundancies since then I'd need to redundantly invoke the code which adds the parameters.  And using PostAsync and PutAsync is a bit more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for some reason you cannot use `async/await` operators,

You can reduce redundancy like this:

```
    public static class Ext
    {
        public static string Finalize(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpResponseMessage)
        {
            return httpResponseMessage
                .Result
                .Content
                .ReadAsStringAsync()
                .Result;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private string Post(string url, ByteArrayContent content, AuthenticationToken token = null)
        {
            return this.CreateClient(token)
                .PutAsync(url, content)
                .Finalize();
        }

        private string Put(string url, StringContent content, AuthenticationToken token)
        {
            return this.CreateClient(token)
                .PostAsync(url, content)
                .Finalize();
        }

        private HttpClient CreateClient(AuthenticationToken token)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            if (token != null)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
            }

            return client;
        }
    }
```

So wrap Client creation in one method, and wrap Finalizing your async stuffs into extention method

Comment: I'm not a fan of static methods, but this is an interesting approach.  I'm not familiar with this use of the "this" keyword, but I think I understand it.  On the other hand, I'm not entirely clear how the system knows to apply the Ext class for the .Finalize() method ?  Am I missing something?

Comment: System applies Ext class because it's extention method. You can read more about them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is something similar to what other languages might call a "Trait" or a "MixIn"?  But how does C# know to apply the extention class to the program class?  I don't see any explicit declaration for that.  Or is that controlled by the visibility of Ext?

Comment: static .. (this.. ) method (extension method) is applied whenever it's in napespace you use (current od applied by `using`), it's like extending predefined type with new method

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `switch` expression. It became surprisingly functional in C#8. You can read more and find samples here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions

Upd: consider using an enum instead of function names to make your code typesafe.

Comment: Cheers for the response, but Robert Cecil Martin describes switch as an abomination which, if it must be used, should be buried deeply in the code.  :-)   I'm looking for a solution which is polymorphic or at least can be done without branching logic.

Comment: *but Robert Cecil Martin describes switch as an abomination which, if it must be used, should be buried deeply in the code* ... it's so funny when you have `.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` **which is far, far, far worst**

Comment: I'll admit that doesn't make for a pleasant read, but that's the DSL I've got to work with.  I could extract some variables, but I can't think of any names which would add useful information into this context.  If you have a better way to do this, plesae let me know.\